# Algorithm to parse an "ordered" List and find respective sums and addends?

Tags: python, algorithm, list, sum, stack

Sorry if this has been asked before, but I have been searching for days and have found no help relating to my problem.

What I am attempting to work on is a method to parse a list (similar to a budget sheet) and assign the indices to parents or children. A parent is a sum of its children, and a Child is an addend for that parent (or a number that has no parent).

for example: `[1,2,3,6]`, where 6 is the parent of 1, 2, and 3.

or a more complex example: `[1,2,3,6,1,4,3,8,14,3,2,3,8,1,4,3,8,16,30]`,

with 30 being the "root" of this list, because 30 = 14 + 16, 14 = 6 + 8, 6 = 1 + 2 + 3, etc. The list will always be somewhat in order, that is children will always appear together before their parent (except of course when parents are children of another parent). I was trying to find the most efficient way of doing this, and my 2 solutions use stacks, but they're not quite 100% correct, as the 2 examples above fail. Here is the pseudo code for both:

**Solution attempt 1**

```
stack = []
for number in list
    if stack.isEmpty()
        stack.push(number)
    elif stack.peek() > number
        stack.push(number)
    else
        copy = stack
        temp = []
        current = number
        while current > 0
            popped = copy.pop()
            temp.push(popped)
            current -= popped
        if current == 0
            while temp
                child = temp.pop()
                child.parent = number
            stack = copy
    stack.push(number)
```

**Solution attempt 2**

```
stack = []
for number in list
    stack.push(number)

while stack.size() > 1
    child = stack.pop()
    copy = stack
    temp = []
    if child > stack.peek()
        while current > 0 and copy.size() > 0
            popped = copy.pop()
            temp.push(popped)
            current -= popped    
        if current == 0
            while temp
                child = temp.pop()
                child.parent = number
```

Any ideas or thoughts would be greatly appreciated. I'm banging my head against the wall at this point.

**Edit**

**Complex example solution**
`[1,2,3,6,1,4,3,8,14,3,2,3,8,1,4,3,8,16,30]`

```
                   30
            /             \
      14                     16
    /      \              /        \
  6          8           8             8
/  |  \   /  |  \     /  |   \     /   |   \
1  2   3  1  4   3   3   2    3   1    4    3
```

Comment: Why 30 is root for the list? Can you edit your question and post some sample input and expected output?

Comment: 30 is the "root" parent because it's the total sum of all the other parents. See edit

Comment: Can you provide the full explanation for the complex example? I see 1 + 2 + 3 = 6, but then how do you group 1,4,3,8,14...?

Comment: Do you assume all integers are positive?

Comment: There may be edge cases with negative integers/doubles, but for the most part the lists will be positive

Comment: There is a particular solution you want? (and in case which one?) I can imagine the one which has the last element as root, but at the most general level if all elements are siblings and no one has children would respect your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an interesting problem. Here is a recursive solution using lists as trees (root at index 0, children at following indexes):

```
def get_tree(nums, trees=None):
    trees = trees or []
    if not nums:
        return trees[0] if len(trees) == 1 else None
    val, *nums = nums
    for i in range(len(trees)):
        if val == sum(c[0] for c in trees[i:]):
            result = get_tree(nums,  trees[:i] + [[val] + trees[i:]])
            if result:
                return result
    return get_tree(nums, trees + [[val]])

print(get_tree([1, 2, 3, 6]))
print(get_tree([1, 2, 3, 6, 1, 4, 3, 8, 14, 3, 2, 3, 8, 1, 4, 3, 8, 16, 30]))
print(get_tree([1, 2, 3, 7]))
print(get_tree([1, 2, 3]))

# [6, [1], [2], [3]]
# [30, [14, [6, [1], [2], [3]], [8, [1], [4], [3]]], [16, [8, [3], [2], [3]], [8, [1], [4], [3]]]]
# None
# [3, [1], [2]]
```

The logic of `get_tree` goes as follows:

- You collect a list of trees while iterating the list of numbers
- at each position in `nums`, you can do one of two things:

  - take any suffix of trees of the end of the tree list (`trees[i:]`) and put them as children under a new tree with the current number as root
  - add the current number as a new tree to the stack
- when you reach the end of list and have exactly one tree on the stack, that is the result

You are essentially given a post-order traversal and generate all possible trees from it, weeding out the ones that have sum mismatches along the way. For positive integers, this process is deterministic, i.e. there is either exactly one valid tree or none. For non-positive integers, there may be multiple possible valid trees. The trivial example would be a list of only zeroes, where any tree would be valid.

Comment: Nice. Are such sequences canonical, ie. is there a unique solution or none? If yes, they surely have a name.

Comment: @Vroomfondel Not sure if I understand you correctly. The sequence is a post-order traversal of a tree. In general, multiple trees can produce the same post-order traversal sequence. Thus, whether the solution is unique depends on the imposed restrictions. In this case, the sum restriction alone is not enough (see the zeroes example). But, with strictly positive numbers, it should be, even though I did not formally prove it :)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

If your input is sorted as stated in question, you can leverage `sorted()` function and recursion.

Example (assuming non-empty input):

```
def _get_tree(lst):   
    new_children, cnt = [], 0
    for idx, v in sorted(enumerate(lst[:-1]), key=lambda k: k[1], reverse=True):
        cnt += v
        new_children.append((idx, v))

        if cnt == lst[-1]:
            start, new_children = 0, sorted(new_children, key=lambda k: k[0])
            for idx2, v2 in new_children:
                if idx2 - start == 0:
                    yield lst[start]
                else:
                    yield [v2, [*_get_tree(lst[start:idx2+1])]]
                start = idx2 + 1
            break

def get_tree(lst):
    return list([lst[-1], [*_get_tree(lst)]])

print(get_tree([1,2,3,6,1,4,3,8,14,3,2,3,8,1,4,3,8,16,30]))
print(get_tree([1, 2, 3]))
print(get_tree([1, 2, 3, 6]))
print(get_tree([1, 2, 3, 7]))
```

Prints:

```
[30, [[14, [[6, [1, 2, 3]], [8, [1, 4, 3]]]], [16, [[8, [3, 2, 3]], [8, [1, 4, 3]]]]]]
[3, [1, 2]]
[6, [1, 2, 3]]
[7, []]
```